# The prebuilt agents weather, news have no response

Tags: dialogflow-es

I tried to import prebuilt agents of dialogflow. Jokes works well, but News and Weather give no response ( no error information is given too). I have tested web-demo link and my own code( logined and sent query-data to dialogflow). Both of testing did work for Jokes, not for News and Weather.
I use a free dialogflow ES version, need I upgrade to a paid plan to let them work?